# Diacritics in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I am working on real estate website for Poland.

I have a search section with autocomplete function that refresh search results when user stops typing.

Everything works fine when i type some non-accent city name, like "Warszawa".

The problem is, when i type a word with accent, such as "Kraków". Autocomplete finds the marker on a map, until i don't type letter "ó". When i type a word without accent like this - "Krakow", script still can't find the marker on the map.

I've been thinking how to solve this for the couple of hours, and can't make it work.

My website to check this out is here: http://ultimate.houser.pl/nieruchomosci/

My code is:

```
function getPredictions(request, response){

    tmpList = [];

    if (typeof $.goMap.map === 'object') {

        $.goMap.predictions.getQueryPredictions({ input: 'Polska, ' + request.term }, function(predictions, status){

            for ( i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {

                place_req = {
                    placeId: predictions[i].place_id
                };

                $.goMap.places.getDetails( place_req, function(place, status){

                    miasto='', woj='', ulica='';

                    for ( i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                      addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

                      if (addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                        woj = ', ' + place.address_components[i].long_name;
                      };
                      if (addressType == 'locality') {
                        miasto = '' + place.address_components[i].long_name;
                      };
                      if (addressType == 'route') {
                        ulica = ', ' + place.address_components[i].long_name;
                      };
                    }
                    // val = miasto + woj + ulica;
                    if (woj != '') {
                        val = miasto + woj;
                    };

                    if ( tmpList.indexOf(val) < 0 && val.length > 0) {
                        val = val.replace(/województwo/i,'').trim();
                        // val.replace(',','');
                        tmpList.push(val);
                        response(tmpList);
                    };

                });
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to URL Encode the query? I'm not sure if that will work, though. The [autocomplete example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) from the official documentation seems to work with special characters when I tried to input Krakow and Kraków I think you can look into those and check if you missed out on anything

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue of the Autocomplete(it returns results, otherwise you wouldn't see anything in the dropdown).

The problem: when you test the list of markers( `div.where`) against the value of `input#search-where` you remove the diacritics from the input-value

[ajax_search.js?ver=4.4.1](http://ultimate.houser.pl/wp-content/themes/glocal/scripts/ajax_search.js?ver=4.4.1) Line 227

```
    where = removeDiacritics( $("#search-where").val() );
```

But you don't remove the diacritics from the innerHtml of `div.where`

You must either remove the diacritics from both sides or leave them as they are.